# php parse string and copy elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

Let's say, I have a dynamic string like this:

```
$string = "ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL";
```

or this

```
$string = "ABC-DEF-GHI";
```

string is **changable**

what I want to do is to parse string, duplicate all elements besides first one and last one like this:

```
ABC-DEF
DEF-GHI
GHI-JKL
```

or like this

```
ABC-DEF
DEF-GHI
```

What should be the logic here? How can I achieve that?

PS:  I know I can use

```
explode("-", $string);
```

which gives me an array like this:

```
[0]->ABC
[1]->DEF
[2]->GHI
[3]->JKL
```

But I don't know how to **foreach** this string. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php

$string = "ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL";

$parts = explode("-", $string);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($parts) - 1; $i ++) {
        echo $parts[$i] . '-' . $parts[$i + 1] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Your prepared solution:

```
<?php
$string = "ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL";
$stringArray = explode("-", $string);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($stringArray); $i++) {
    if ($stringArray[$i + 1] != "") {
        echo $stringArray[$i] . "-" . $stringArray[$i + 1] . "\n";
    }
}
?>
```

EDIT: I forgot to add, please edit `"\n"` to whatever newline separator you need.

Comment: yupp and "E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 4" (if you paste it in phpfiddle you can see it)